# R Shiny: How to get choices of dynamic shiny input

Tags: r, shiny

I have different fields of SelectInput which are dynamically generated. I am trying to get choices of each SelectInput but failed like below:

```
input[[ paste0("FilterField","_",rowNumber)]]$choices
```

getting like: NA NA NA NA.

**Updated:**

I have a created 4 selectInput's here, I want to get choices of first dropdown. Please help me on getting this.

```
library(shiny)

choices = c("","Employee","State","City","Status")

ui = fluidPage(
  box(
    uiOutput("InputUI"),

    actionButton(
      inputId = "ENTER",
      style = "simple",
      size = "sm",
      label="Print Number of Choices in Console"
    )
  )

)
server = function(input, output) {
  filterRow=reactiveValues(
    CurrentRow=4
  )

  output$InputUI=renderUI({
    box(
      div(
        selectInput(
          inputId=paste("FilterField",1,sep = "_"),
          label="",
          choices=choices,
          multiple=F,
          selectize = F
        )
      ),

      div(
        selectInput(
          inputId=paste("FilterField",2,sep = "_"),
          label="",
          choices=choices,
          multiple=F,
          selectize = F
        )
      ),

      div(
        selectInput(
          inputId=paste("FilterField",3,sep = "_"),
          label="",
          choices=choices,
          multiple=F,
          selectize = F
        )
      ),

      div(
        selectInput(
          inputId=paste("FilterField",4,sep = "_"),
          label="",
          choices=choices,
          multiple=F,
          selectize = F
        )
      )
    )

  })

  observeEvent(input$ENTER,{
     print(input[[ paste0("FilterField","_",1)]]["choices"])
  })

}
shinyApp(ui,server,options=list(launch.browser=F))
```

I have update latest code, please help on this.

Comment: Please submit a reproducible example, in general if you have multiple choices set to True you index it with `x = input$choices; x[1];x[2]...`

Comment: I need of values of that dropdown, dynamically I am adding and removing the values for the dropdown conditonally

Comment: Please submit a reproducible example with ui, server and a shinyApp() call.

Comment: updated @Sada93

Comment: This code itself isn't working

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you decide that `$choices` exists in shiny? There is only `input$inputId` values. If you need to change choices, you can use

> updateSelectInput()

function and pass to it new choices computed conditionally.